# Linux install command for mingw?

Tags: windows, makefile, installation, mingw, mingw32

When trying to build a library from source using `make` and MinGW, I realized (from errors) that I don't have the `install` command, which I understand to be a combination of `cp`, `chown`, `chmod`, `strip`, and maybe some other stuff. I figured, hey, someone's got to have a copy of that out there, right? But unfortunately the name of the binary makes it near impossible to search for with any search engine.

Does anyone know of an existing MinGW-compatible version of `install`?

Comment: my MSYS setup has a `install` binary; it's so old that I don't remember how I installed it and whether I did something special to get it. Try installing MSYS, mingw has some kind of package management these days; it should be easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MinGW as a cross-compiler, hosted on Linux, (as your question title might be construed to imply), the native /usr/bin/install on the Linux host itself serves admirably; (FWIW, this is *exactly* how my own MinGW development platform is set up).

OTOH, if you really mean "where can I find a *Linux-like* install utility to accompany MinGW running on MS-Windows?", then (as Diego notes) you will find it among MinGW.org's MSYS tools; running `mingw-get install msys-base` will install it for you, (assuming you are using mingw-get to manage your MinGW installation).